# Poincare-Miranda on a torus

Tags: real-analysis

The [Poincare-Miranda theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Miranda_theorem) involves $d$ functions on a $d$-dimensional cube. Function $i$ is negative in one direction of dimension $i$ and positive in the opposite direction of dimension $i$. The theorem says that there must be a point in the cube in which all functions are 0.

Is there a parallel theorem on a $d$-dimensional torus, where the boundary conditions are replaced by [oddity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions)?

To be concrete, let $d=2$. A 2-dimensional torus is a cartesian product of 2 circles: $S^1 \times S^1$.

There are 2 continuous functions: $f_1(x_1,x_2), f_2(x_1,x_2)$, where $x_i$ is a point on the circle in dimension $i$. Function $i$ is *odd* in dimension $i$, i.e: $f_1(-x_1,x_2)=-f_1(x_1,x_2)$, and similarly $f_2(x_1,-x_2)=-f_2(x_1,x_2)$.

(Alternatively, the two functions can be defined as: $f_1(\theta_1,\theta_2), f_2(\theta_1,\theta_2)$, where $\theta_i$ is an *angle* on the circle in dimension $i$. Function $i$ is *odd* in dimension $i$, i.e: $f_1(\theta_1+\pi,\theta_2)=-f_1(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ and $f_2(\theta_1,\theta_2+\pi)=-f_2(\theta_1,\theta_2)$).

**Is this true that there must be a point in the torus in which all functions are 0?**

The intuition for this variant is the same as for the original variant: for each function $i$, there must be a "wall" of 0 which separates the positive side of $i$ from its negative side. Each wall is in a different dimension, so they must meet in a point. But is it true?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you mean by "odd", but since the $f_{i}$ must be continuous, it seems "oddness" implies $f_{i}(\dots, 0, \dots) = 0$ if the argument $0$ occurs in the $i$th variable, so that each $f_{i}$ vanishes at the origin. (If necessary to make this sensible, lift all the $f_{i}$ to $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ by periodicity.) If you mean the ordinary definition of "odd", then of course each $f_{i}$ vanishes at the origin (or at the image of the origin in the torus).

Comment: @user86418 I edited the question to make it clearer. I treat a torus as a cartesian product of unit circles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus . Hence, the torus does not contain the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$View the unit circle as the set of unit complex numbers, and define a map $f:S^{1} \times S^{1} \to \Reals^{2}$ by
$$
f(e^{i\theta_{1}}, e^{i\theta_{2}})
  = \bigl(\underbrace{\cos(\theta_{1} + \theta_{2})}_{f_{1}(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2})},
          \underbrace{\sin(\theta_{1} + \theta_{2})}_{f_{2}(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2})}\bigr).
$$
For all $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$,
\begin{align*}
f_{1}(\theta_{1} + \pi, \theta_{2})
  &= \cos(\theta_{1} + \theta_{2} + \pi)
  = -\cos(\theta_{1} + \theta_{2}), \\
f_{2}(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2} + \pi)
  &= \sin(\theta_{1} + \theta_{2} + \pi)
  = -\sin(\theta_{1} + \theta_{2}),
\end{align*}
but $\|f(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2})\| = 1$, so the origin is not in the image of $f$; that is, $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ do not vanish simultaneously.

To extend this idea to an $n$-dimensional torus, define
$$
f_{1}(\theta_{1}, \dots, \theta_{n}) = \cos(\theta_{1} + \theta_{2}),\quad
f_{2}(\theta_{1}, \dots, \theta_{n}) = \sin(\theta_{1} + \theta_{2}),\quad
f_{i}(\theta_{1}, \dots, \theta_{n}) = 0,\ i > 2.
$$

The topological point seems to be that a cube is contractible, and "oddness" (even just the sign conditions on the boundary in the Poincaré-Miranda theorem) is enough to imply the image of the boundary of the cube encloses the origin, so by continuity the origin is in the image of $f$. By contrast, an $n$-torus has lots of $1$-dimensional homology, so it's "easy" to wind the image around the origin without hitting the origin, even if the mapping is odd. (At least, that's what naturally suggested the example above.)

Comment: Thanks for the example and the topological explanatin.

Comment: You're very welcome. :) Incidentally, my initial impression pointed the other way: A map $f:(S^{1})^{n} \to \mathbf{R}^{n}$ induces a "fully periodic" map $F:\mathbf{R}^{n}\to\mathbf{R}^{n}$, and (modulo my (mis-)understanding of what you meant by "odd") it looked possible to find some translate of a fundamental cube satisfying the hypotheses of the Poincaré-Miranda theorem. On closer inspection, however, it seemed nothing prevented the zero set of $f_{i}$ from "rotating around the $i$th factor as another coordinate varied". That idea suggested the counterexample....